# Of "WebKitErrorDomain error 101" want know the cause

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uisearchbar

```
-(Void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked: (UISearchBar *) activeSearchBar { 
    NSString * query = [searchBar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @ "" withString: @ "+"]; 
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "http://www.google.com/search?q =%@", query]]; 
    NSURLRequest * requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url]; 
    [Home loadRequest: requestObj]; 
} 

-(Void) loadView { 
     [Super loadView]; 
     CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];   
     searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (0.0, 0.0, bounds.size.width, 48.0)]; 
     searchBar.delegate = self; 
     [Self.view addSubview: searchBar];
}
```

I don't speak english and rely on a translator.
Because of the language issue could this be a keyboard problem, or an encoding problem?

The cause of the error follows.
If writing in Korean, the error occur.
but If writing in English, the error does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [list of WebKit errors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Miscellaneous/WebKit_Constants/Reference/reference.html). Specifically, 101 is WebKitErrorCannotShowURL, described as "Indicates a failure in changing a location."